# How should I use defaultdict?

Tags: python

There is a class named Count.

```
def __init__(self, caters):
    self.form = collections.defaultdict(collection.Counter)
    self.caters = {caters: Catergory(caters) for caters in cats}
```

I read information from some files and gave it value,

```
def read_file(file_name, level, counters):
    data = open(file_name).read()
    counters.caters[level].docs.add(file_name)
    for token in blabla:
        counter.form[token][file_name] += 1
```

How am I gonna do if I want to get the total frequency of each token regardless which file it's in?

how to get the frequency of certain word in a certain level, eg. the name of the token is dog, level = 1, I want to get freq[dog][1]?

Comment: you're reading a file into `data` and then we don't see `data` again. Is it relevant somehow?

Comment: Adding some context and clarifying your question will encourage answers and help prevent downvotes on your question. (p.s. it wasn't me!)

Comment: haha. it's a long program and I don't know if it's wise to bring everything in...

Comment: I already read those datas. nothing else, just the frequency for some word in certain file. I have saved the name for the file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others, I'm not sure I've got enough context to give anything comprehensive. But this line:

```
counter.form[token][file_name] += 1
```

says to me that `counter.form` is going to end up containing a separate count for each token/file_name combination. This is backed up by what you said is the initialisation of the counter:

```
self.form = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
```

That says that `self.form` is a default dictionary, whose default values are instances of `collection.Counter` (which is basically `defaultdict(int)` with a few extra methods, IIRC). So, basically, a 2-dimensional counter.

If you want counts of tokens regardless of which file they're in, then you basically don't want `file_name` to be a parameter of the counter, and the counter needs to be 1-dimensional. So I'd look at changing the initialisation of your counter to:

```
self.form = collections.Counter()
```

And change your count incrementing to:

```
counter.form[token] += 1
```

You possibly need more changes, based on the structure of the rest of your program. But hopefully this will get you in the right direction.

Comment: that's exatly what I mean! For now, before I change anything, how to get the frequency of certain word in certain level, eg. token = dog, level = 1, I want to get freq[token][level]?

Comment: @user1325302 Then you go back to using a 2-dimensional counter, but use `level` as the second dimension instead of `file_type`...

Comment: Great job sussing out a challenging question, @Ben. +1

Answer (score 0):

I use collections.defaultdict(int) to count instances of tokens. You could apply code like this across all files you are interested in, using the same token counter collection for each file (token_counts in my example):

```
token_counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for token in line.split():
            token_counts[token] += 1
for token, count in token_counts.items():
    print token, count
```

I must admit that I found your question a little vague. This is my best guess as to what you are looking for.

Comment: what if I want to print each 'count'? Write a loop?
    print count[0], count[1]
I cannot list all the things I wanna print.